# migrate datas in sql data server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-migration

We have an existing windows application using a database. We migrated to web application using the structure of windows application database , but made few changes like changing the table name and added few columns in tables.

Now if my customer has this windows application already installed in his system and he now migrates to web application.

My requirement is , if my customer already has the windows application database installed in his system, he wants all the datas from the windows application db inside the webapplication db and all the details from the windows application now inside the web application, so that the customer can now start using web application instead of windows application immediately.

What is the best way to migrate the datas inside the windows application into the web application database.?

Comment: Is the Web Application DB hosted locally on the same environment as the Windows App DB? I'm unsure if you're looking to migrate data from a remote location to a centralised location, or if you're looking to move data around within the same environment.

Comment: Are you you using Entity Framework to query the DB or you are querying the DB directly?

Comment: @StewartMbofana I use entity framework for web application.

Comment: @PeteEbdon thankyou for the reply.:)
Please explain me what you actually mean by environment?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague on detail. You say your customers are using a Windows Application database, but are they hosting the database or is it hosted elsewhere and they're connecting to it? You then mention a Web Application, but once again is that something you're shipping off to users or is that something you're hosting? If you want to migrate potentially large amounts of data then the specifics become important, as from the question I can't tell if the databases are side by side or on opposite sides of the globe.

Comment: In that case your web app can just use the same EF layer as you were using with the Windows App. I would suggest you put the EF layer in a separate Data Access Layer project and then reference the dll either from the web app or the Windows App. This means you can use both apps with the same DB or remove one whenever you want to.

Comment: @PeteEbdon windows application database is present in every client's machine. All i need to do is to transfer the data from windows application database to webapplication database(which is present in remote). This makes the client to migrate to web application with the data in the windows application so that the client can continue using the web application immediately.